# 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: no mechanism available

Tags: postfix, sasl, saslauthd

I'm using Debian 7, with postfix/courier.
When I attempt to login using SMTP I get the following error

```
telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
ehlo localhost
250-mail.mydomain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbQ==
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
dGVzdA==
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: no mechanism available
```

I've been googling for hours to try to fix this :( I have another server installed in the exact same way, also on Debian 7 which works just fine.

Here is the output of saslfinger:

```
saslfinger -s

saslfinger - postfix Cyrus sasl configuration Thu Mar 12 18:07:21 EDT 2015
version: 1.0.4
mode: server-side SMTP AUTH

-- basics --
Postfix: 2.9.6
System: Debian GNU/Linux 7 \n \l

-- smtpd is linked to --
        libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007fd3d5d62000)

-- active SMTP AUTH and TLS parameters for smtpd --
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes


-- listing of /usr/lib/sasl2 --
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar  5 08:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 44 root root 12288 Mar 12 17:22 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     4 Mar  5 08:27 berkeley_db.active
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     4 Jun  9  2013 berkeley_db.txt

-- listing of /etc/postfix/sasl --
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  5 10:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 12 17:22 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  295 Mar 12 17:36 smtpd.conf




-- content of /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf --
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login
allow_plaintext: true
auxprop_plugin: mysql
sql_hostnames: 127.0.0.1
sql_user: --- replaced ---
sql_passwd: --- replaced ---
sql_database: mail
sql_select: select password from users where email = '%u'
saslauthd_path: /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/mux


-- content of /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf --
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login
allow_plaintext: true
auxprop_plugin: mysql
sql_hostnames: 127.0.0.1
sql_user: --- replaced ---
sql_passwd: --- replaced ---
sql_database: mail
sql_select: select password from users where email = '%u'
saslauthd_path: /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/mux



-- active services in /etc/postfix/master.cf --
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

-- mechanisms on localhost --
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
```

all that gets written to `/var/log/mail.log` is

```
Mar 12 18:36:38 myhostname postfix/smtpd[4099]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 12 18:37:14 myhostname postfix/smtpd[4099]: warning: localhost[127.0.0.1]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: no mechanism available
```

and last

```
 testsaslauthd -u test@mydomain.com -p test -f /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/mux -s smtp
0: OK "Success."
```

I can't figure out what is causing this to happen, from what I have read it looks to be related to postfix's chrooting, but I don't see anything wrong in the configuration.

Comment: Post the maillog entry when this happened...

Comment: @masegaloeh, `/var/log/mail.log` is not written to during the telnet session, I don't know if it supposed to be like that or not.

Comment: @masegaloeh, I was looking at the log file on wrong server, sorry about that, I'll add it now.

Comment: Please see links I gave above. Looks like you have to comment out `auxprop_plugin` line.

Comment: @masegaloeh, If I comment out `auxprop_plugin` like the "duplicate" suggests, I get the error `535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: generic failure`

Comment: Any **new** error message in mail.log?

Comment: @masegaloeh, yes, `warning: SASL authentication failure: cannot connect to saslauthd server: No such file or directory`

Comment: Your saslauthd daemon doesn't running. Please find out why. Check the syslog file.

Comment: `saslauthd` was running, I had it open in the foreground with `-d`

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this by changing the `auxprop_plugin: mysql` to `auxprop_plugin: sql`, I don't understand why this is different on the same version of debian, but it works now.